# map_server question

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm still new to ROS so I don't know much...
but I was wondering where do you guys usually get the map from for the map_server.

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196515/map_server-question/) by [pikaboo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20658/pikaboo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either use an existing map or create your own.
For creating a new map, you can use [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)

For existing maps, you can find some examples [here](https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_maps) .

A map is defined by an image file where black means obstacle and white means free (depending on some threshold on pixel intensity) and by a .YAML file where map resolution, origin and some thresholds are defined. More information on the [map_server page](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server).

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1